# TypeScript complains with and without lib

Tags: typescript, async-await

I'm trying to add an async function in a TypeScript project. The code looks like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (id, c, t) => { ... });
```

TypeScript complains:

> error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor. Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your --lib option

When I add `lib: ['es2015']` to tsconfig, TypeScript starts complaining about all calls to `console.log` saying that console is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [default libs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for `es5` are `DOM,ES5`, so if you specify `es2015` you will also need to add `dom` explicitly as `console` is defined in the `dom` library. Sample `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Typescript has a modular approach to the default libraries, so you can include only what is available based on your environment.

Comment: This almost works! tslint is still complaining about it! $#@$#@$#@. I'll just tell it to ignore this check.

Comment: #@!#@!#!@ I couldn't find a way to disable this message! It's either tslint or PyCharm.

Comment: What message are you getting ?

Comment: It's PyCharm, not tslint (i've disabled tslint and the problem persists). I get a red squiggly line under the async callback with the exact same message - that there's no Promise constructor or es2015 is not in lib. The code transpiles and runs properly, so this is probably a PyCharm bug.

Comment: I ended up putting the callback in its own async function and just pass that function to addListener. The code is now nicer looking and there's no squiggly red line.